# Populating Websites form fields

Tags: jquery, copy, paste, populate

Say if i have a filed out form with all the data infront of me, but i want to take all that data and pre populate a form on another website is this possible or am i asking for miracles?

Basically i have this issue where i have to site every night and take information from one site and the copy and peaste it into a form on another site, nightmare.

Ideal situation i could have a grab button that grabs all the data from my form and stores it somehow then i could access the other website and almost do a copy paste into the fields.

Or would their be a way to actually just send the data straight from my form to theirs systems to make a payment??

Any ideas or help to make my life easier???

Comment: there is a **form auto fill-up** in all major browser, do you aware on that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how to write a .NET application that would do that.  I'm sure other app languages could do the same.  I don't know about anything javascript wise (jQuery for instance) that could do this.

Robodude has probably the best solution in using autohotkey.  It's pretty powerful for tasks like this.

Comment: ok cheers guys i was thinking maybe is their a way to directly submitting data to a website. as long as all the info is correct ie card details etc and product could you auto simulate a purchase with the data i have on my site??

Answer (score 1):

I've had to perform something similar in the past. Although I didn't look into a JQuery solution, I was able to achieve the desired results by using http://www.autohotkey.com/ to create a script that would copy the information, tab over to the next window, paste, tab back, copy again, rinse and repeat.

Comment: wow that was an insanely quick response. Cheers ill have a look at this now.

Comment: Gutted im on a mac trying to find an alternative looking at this typinator

Comment: @iSimpleDesign: Look at AppleScripts

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the website you may be able to post directly to their page, which is basically skipping their form, or you may be able to pass their input field parameters in the query string if they are not being picky about whether the data is read from the get or post variables. Not quite the same as filling out the form, but it could work depending upon the site.

As far as filling out a form using Javascript as far as I know this is not possible. I would love to know how to do so if it is though.  I wanted to populate the fields on a page loaded in an Iframe that had a different site loaded. I did a lot of research, but I could not figure out a way to do it.

But if you are doing this for personal reasons, just to make filling out things quicker, then you can use the built in auto-fill of the browser, or you could record a macro using Imacros plugin for firefox [(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863/)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863/) to fill in forms for you.

Comment: I've used this method a number of times before - hot-wiring my own content straight to their form handler, rather than dealing with the middle-man (being their form). It is very effective, in my experience.